# get session state (time) of RedisSessionStateProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, redis

I am wondering if there is any possibility to get to know the current session state in the meaning of how much idle time is remaining before the sessions gets closed by the provider.
Background of the question:
I want to handle the known issue of sessions getting closes during pure client side actions (no ajax calls extending the current session)

My config as is:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="sportloop.redis.cache.windows.net" port="6380" accessKey="xyz" ssl="true" throwOnError="true" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" databaseId="0" applicationName="sportloop" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: Check this if it can help :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net

Comment: Okay thx. But isn't there a direct way to receive that information instead of creating a "proxy" session timeout on the client side?